# Using dates as criterion for COUNTIFS in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

So I'm currently making a recruiting data sheet for an online community. I'm trying to make it as automated as possible without actually making a bot to do it.

How can I make a `COUNTIF`(or similar) that counts the amount of people join within a time period?

My current strategy was to do this:

```
=COUNTIF(D3:D900,"2/\**$/2020")
```

Its not getting the expected results, but I'm also not quite good with Regex in Google Sheets. This strategy is attempting to get a result for the amount of people who joined in the month of February using the dates.

Comment: Welcome. Your questions (1 & 2) are very  different form each other. Please split them in two separate questions. Also, do read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Thanks @marikamitsos . Will do. I'm a bit new here so the help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How can I make a COUNTIF(or similar) that counts the amount of people join within a time period?*

You do not really need any regex function. You can use the different versions of the following formula instead.

1. To find **all values** within the second month (February)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(V21:V38,"<>",MONTH(U21:U38), "="&2))
```

2. To just find the `Y` values  within the second month (February)

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(V21:V38,"Y",MONTH(U21:U38), "="&2))
```

Have a look at the [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rEC9Oa3tLhnVGeWsKAiCoI8-TG_OY-NLODU3noHhTOo/edit#gid=595449507&range=F2) I created in your sheet.

[image]

**How the formula *`=ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(V21:V38,"<>",MONTH(U21:U38), "="&2))`* works**:

`COUNTIFS` looks into the first range `U21:V21` and in cell `V21` it calculates the value according to the criterion `"<>"` which means not empty.
It then goes to the next cell `U21` where the function `MONTH` has already extracted the month from cell that in our case is different from the second criterion `2` and in this case `COUNTIFS` drops the value.
Then `ARRAYFORMULA` takes over and repeats the process in the next row and keeps on doing that till it hits the end of our range on row 38.
The final result is 6, which means only 6 pairs met **both** the criteria.

Functions used:

- [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [COUNTIFS](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550)
- [MONTH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093052)

Comment: Do you mind breaking down how that line works? I'm only a bit better with excel than I am with stack.

Comment: No problem. First of all, did it work for you?

Comment: It did not, but I'm not sure what variables I need to edit in it.

Comment: Could you please share a test sheet?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rEC9Oa3tLhnVGeWsKAiCoI8-TG_OY-NLODU3noHhTOo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you! I deduced the syntax from some testing.

Comment: _"Thank you! I deduced the syntax from some testing."_ What do you mean? Did the formulas  work for you or not? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and maybe [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still a bit new to this. The formula worked perfectly and I figured out how it worked on my own. I'm going to accept the answer now.